# Regex replace whole word

Tags: c#, regex

I have  this string:

> Element 60:80 Node 1 2 3 Elm 55      Element 60 mpc 1:999  Elem 123

I want to replace all "Elm" "E" and "Elem" in my string to "Element". I don't want to replace "Node" to "NodElement" so I need to use word boundaries to match only whole words.

For that I'm using this regex:

```
Regex regexElements = new Regex("\b(E|Elm|Elem)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match m in regexElements.Matches(str))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Match: " + m.Value");
}

str = regexElements.Replace(str, "Element"); //str is my string
```

But I don't see any replacement nor a MessageBox is being shown.
The funny thing is that I can still target the desired words using Notepad++ search. 
What is happening here? 
Thanks

Comment: You're using `n.Value` instead of `m.Value`. Also, you can simplify your regex to `@"\bE(le?m)?\b"`

Comment: You could possibly look into Lookahead Regex, the following link may help http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio (of and after VS2012) you can simply do the replacement inside the IDE, provided that you have the source file. Sublime Text can do it, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to raw your regex. `\b` alone will not mean a word boundary (I'm not entirely sure what it means, but it's not a literal `b`, so it might be something like backspace). So either you use `\\b` or you use `@` like in my comment, so that the final code becomes:

```
Regex regexElements = new Regex(@"\b(E|Elm|Elem)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match m in regexElements.Matches(str))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Match: " + m.Value);
}

str = regexElements.Replace(str, "Element"); //str is my string
```

Or

```
Regex regexElements = new Regex("\\b(E|Elm|Elem)\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match m in regexElements.Matches(str))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Match: " + m.Value);
}

str = regexElements.Replace(str, "Element"); //str is my string
```

I also propose this regex which is slightly more optimised:

```
@"\bE(le?m)?\b"
```

Comment: @James Thanks! And it's no wonder, there were quite a few issues with the supplied sample code =P

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regex for that  :

```
String yourString = "Element 60:80 Node 1 2 3 Elm 55 Element 60 mpc 1:999 Elem 123" ; 

yourString = yourString.Replace("Elem", "Element").Replace("E ", "Element ").Replace("Elm", "Element");
```

Comment: As I'm new in regular expressions I would like to learn why the initial way of solving this is not working. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Yes there is, this will replace any occurance of `E` / `Elem` and `Elm`, however, the OP said they don't want to replace scenarios like `NodeElem` etc.